# Random Forest prediction error in R "No forest component in the object"

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, raster

I am attempting to use a random forest regressor to classify a raster stack, but an error does not allow a prediction of "area_pct", have I not trained the model properly?

`d100` is my dataset with predictor variables `d100[,4:ncol(d100)]` and prediction variable `d100["area_pct"]`.

```
#change na values to zero
d100[is.na(d100)] <- 0
set.seed(100)

#split dataset into training (70%) and testing (30%)
id<- sample(2,nrow(d100), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7,0.3))
train_100<- d100[id==1,]
test_100 <- d100[id==2,]
```

train random forest model with randomForest package, this appears to work fine

```
final_CC_rf_20 = randomForest(x=train[,4:ncol(train)], y= train$area_pct, 
    xtest=test[,4:ncol(test)], ytest=test$area_pct, mtry=14, importance=TRUE, ntree = 600)
```

Then I try to predict a raster.

New raster stack with predictor variables

```
sentinel_2_20 <- stack( paste(getwd(), "Sentinel_SR_clip_20.tif", sep="/") )
area_classified_20_2018 <- predict(object = final_CC_rf_20 , newdata = sentinel_2_20,type = 'response', progress = 'window')
```

but error pops up:

```
#Error in predict.randomForest(object = final_CC_rf_20, newdata = sentinel_2_20,  : 
#  No forest component in the object
```

any help would be extremely useful

Comment: Try to provide a reproducible example - it makes it easier for people to help

Answer (score 0):

The arguments you are using for predict (with raster data) are not correct. The first argument, `object`, should be the raster data, the second argument, `model`, should be the fitted model. There is no argument `newdata`.

Another problem is that you use `keep.forest=FALSE` which is the default when `xtest` is not NULL. You could set `keep.forest=TRUE` but that is not a good approach, generally, as you should fit your model with *all* data before you make a prediction (you are no longer evaluating your model). Thus, I would suggest fitting your model without `xtest`, like this

```
rfmod <- randomForest(x=d100[,4:ncol(train)], y=d100$area_pct, 
                       mtry=14, importance=TRUE, ntree = 600)
```

And then do

```
p <- predict(sentinel_2_20, rfmod, type='response')
```

See `?raster::predict` or `?terra::predict` for working examples

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this appears to have worked!

Comment: 'Error in predict.randomForest(model, blockvals, ...) : 
  No forest component in the object' I changed the code but I am still getting the same error

Comment: I have now also commented on how to fit the model.